# Which Google Workspace API to use to verify domain added in Workspace admin

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-api-python-client

I have created a domain alias in my google workspace account.
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/domainAliases

Now that domain is in unverified state and i need a automated way to verify that domain.

I tried the google site verification API but that look like is only for google search console and not workspace domain alais

https://developers.google.com/site-verification/v1/invoking

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Directory API does not have an available method for the domain verification.